# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof involving differentiation in a defined neighborhood

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The problem states: Suppose $f'(b) = M$ and $M <0$. Find $\delta>0$ so that if $x\in (b-\delta, b)$, then $f(x) > f(b).$

This intuitively makes sense, but I am not exactly sure how to find $\delta$. I greatly appreciate any help I can receive.

Comment: I changed $\epsilon-\delta$ to $\epsilon$-$\delta$.  When the hyphen is _inside_ the $\TeX$ code, then it gets rendered as a minus sign rather as a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the definition of derivative will imply that
$$
\lim_{x\to b^-}\frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}=M.
$$
But, $M<0$ and $b-x>0$.

Comment: If it were not for the fact that I had to find delta, that would definitely work.

Comment: You find delta based on the definition of the limit. Rattle off the definition: For every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$... and there you go, you "found" $\delta$.

Comment: @user42864 To clarify nayrb's comment.  The limit in my answer carries with it an $\epsilon-delta$ definition.  Since $M$ is negative, we can find a $\delta$ so that $\frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}$ is negative.  The details are for you to fill in.

Answer (score 1):

In general you won't be able to 'find $\delta$' explicitly with only information about $f^\prime$, you can only guarantee its existence based on the the limit definition of the derivative.  This is because the value of $\delta$ will depend on the curvature of the function at $b$, i.e. the second derivative (which, unless explicitly stated, doesn't necessarily exist).